# How to avoid duplicate interface code?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

Since interfaces cannot contain implementation, that seems to me to lead to code duplication in the classes that inherit from the interface.  In the example below, pretend that, let's say, the first 10 or so lines that setup reading from a Stream are duplicated.  **Try not to focus on the wording here, but, instead focus on the concept of how easy it is to create duplicate code between each class.**

For example:

```
public interface IDatabaseProcessor
{
   void ProcessData(Stream stream);
}
public class SqlServerProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor
{
    void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
      // setting up logic to read the stream is duplicated code
    }
}
public class DB2Processor : IDatabaseProcessor
{
    void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
      // setting up logic to read the stream is duplicated code
    }
}
```

I realize that using an abstract base class for ProcessData and adding non-abstract members is one solution.  However, what if I really, really want to use an interface instead?

Comment: Why can't you use interface and abstract base class together?

Comment: I think you want to use the `interface` when you actually want to implement it differently in different spots.

Comment: @PavelBakshy - what would be the point?  I would just use an abstract class and define the interface members above as abstract.  You missed the point I'm afraid.

Comment: @MartyE - Yes, but I've often seen that although the implementation is different, it's not so different in that it can't have shared code between implementations.

Comment: @O.O I think you'll just want to put the common code into its own funciton then (the abstract class could be a good place as mentioned below).

Comment: @MartyE - possibly, but then I am dealing with a very thick interface that I will be required to implement even if not all of the classes use this bit of code, but most do.

Comment: I mean that you can define abstract class which implements methods like non abstract. But if you want extract some common logic and save different implementations of your processors you can use something like mixin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to share the code across interfaces is through stateless extension methods. You can build these extensions once, and use it in all classes implementing the interface, regardless of their inheritance chain. This is what .NET did with `IEnumerable<T>` in LINQ, for rather impressive results. This solution is not always possible, but you should prefer it whenever you can.

Another way to share logic is by creating an internal "helper" class. This looks like the right choice in your case: implementations can call the internally shared code as helper's methods, without the need to duplicate any code. For example:

```
internal static class SqlProcessorHelper {
    public void StreamSetup(Stream toSetUp) {
        // Shared code to prepare the stream
    }
}
public class SqlServerProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor {
    void ProcessData(Stream stream) {
        SqlProcessorHelper.StreamSetup(stream);
    }
}
public class DB2Processor : IDatabaseProcessor {
    void ProcessData(Stream stream) {
        SqlProcessorHelper.StreamSetup(stream);
    }
}
```

The helper class does not need to be static: if your shared methods need state, you can make your helper a regular class, and put an instance of it in each implementation of your interface where you would like to share code.

Comment: ...but that can only be shared code that *uses* the interface, not code that helps implement it.

Comment: @Jon This depends on the design: without extensions, methods are often placed in the interface, and end up being implemented over and over - think of Java's `ResultSet` interface, with twice as many methods as it should have (getters by name can be converted to getters by index externally to the interface).

Comment: Extension methods, as in static, as in hard to test?  Seems to violate some OO rule or something.

Comment: Although I wouldn't necessarily say helper class, are you saying to just pult common logic and stick it in a regular class?

Comment: @O.O The "hard to test" rule is incomplete: static methods that use static state are difficult to test indeed. But stateless methods of the kind LINQ provides are very easy to test, because you provide everything you want from the outside, and you have full control, because the method does not have any state.

Comment: @O.O If you do need state, you can certainly make your helper class non-static. This frees up your inheritance hierarchy from the need to inherit an abstract base, effectively replacing inheritance (which is public) with containment (which is private).

Comment: This is the best answer that I can tell for the moment.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. An abstract base class might seem like a good idea at the time... until you need to implement a second interface. You won't get to inherit from another base class!

Comment: but if we have some methods which need instance creation static class wont support

Comment: This solution also works well if the interface-implementing classes have to derive from separate base classes or whenever one is otherwise restricted from creating a common base class.

Comment: @Lijo in that case make the methods part of a regular class and hand an instance of that class to your interface implementations. Composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 19):

This is a case where you would want to use both an interface and an abstract base class.

The only reason you would have both is because another class would not share the abstract base code but would honor the interface.  Consider:

```
public interface IDatabaseProcessor {
   void ProcessData(Stream stream);
}

public abstract class AbstractDatabaseProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor {
    public void ProcessData(Stream stream) {
      // setting up logic to read the stream is not duplicated
    }
}

public class SqlServerProcessor : AbstractDatabaseProcessor {
    //SqlServerProcessor specific methods go here
}

public class DB2Processor : AbstractDatabaseProcessor {
    // DB2Processor specific methods go here
}

public class NonSharedDbProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor {
    void ProcessData(Stream stream) {
      // set up logic that is different than that of AbstractDatabaseProcessor
    }
}
```

<sub>Syntax might be a little off, I am not a regular C# user.  I came here through OOP tag.</sub>

Comment: `Syntax might be a little off, I am not a regular C# user. I came here through OOP tag.` - `ProcessData` method in your abstract class should be marked as public.

Comment: I just don't see the point in creating both, when one would suffice. (the abstract class)

Comment: The problem with this arises when a class must implement several interfaces.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make abstract class AbstractDatabaseProcessor protected instead of public?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Maybe; as mentioned I'm not a regular C# user and am not up-to-date with best practice for those kinds of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

As you already said, one option is using base abstract (or may be even non-abstract) class. Another option is to create another entity to run the common code. In your case it could be `DataProcessor`:

```
internal class DataProcessor
{
    public void Do(Stream stream) 
    {
        // common processing here
    }
}
public class SqlServerProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor
{
    void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
        new DataProcessor().Do(stream);
    }
}
public class DB2Processor : IDatabaseProcessor
{
    void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
        new DataProcessor().Do(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you indicate, an `abstract` class provides the solution. You can use an interface if you "really, really want to;" nothing precludes it. Your `abstract` class should implement `IDatabaseProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to not use a base class while still being able to access `private` and/or `protected` members from the shared code, then the only other option available is [code generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). It's built-in VS (has been for an awful long time) and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use interfaces WITH an abstract base class:

```
public interface IDatabaseProcessor
{
   void ProcessData(Stream stream);
}
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseProcessor : IDatabaseProcessor
{
    public virtual void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
      // setting up logic to read the stream is duplicated code
    }
}
public class SqlServerProcessor : AbstractDatabaseProcessor
{
    public void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
        base.ProcessData(stream);

        // Sql specific processing code
    }
}
public class DB2Processor : AbstractDatabaseProcessor
{
    public void ProcessData(Stream stream)
    {
        base.ProcessData(stream);

        // DB2 specific processing code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather make the `ProcessData()` non virtual with some implementation (for example those shared 10 lines) that calls at some point an abstract method that has to be implemented by all derived (non-abstract) classes. Also mark your `DatabaseProcessor` as `abstract` since you shouldn't be allowed to instantiate this one.

Comment: `ProcessData` should be virtual to prevent hiding.

Comment: But why?  What's the point of using both?  I mean isn't that just working around the interface?  I would never do it this way if I had a choice.  I would just start with an abstract class to begin with.

Comment: I.e. you have an interface to implement (and not only one but many implementations) or you expose an interface so others can implement it their way. For your implementations you create an abstract base class to share some code you otherwise would have to copy. Lets take the upper example: you design an data abstraction layer and expose an interface for specific dialects but implement the SQL and DB2 ones yourself with code shared in an abstract class. Others don't rely on your abstract base type and just roll their own internal logic.

Comment: Interface describe contract, it is decencies of API building and abstract classes used in order to avoid duplication is this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have some hierachy of classes to implement an interface to share some implementation of the interface.

I.e. in your case you can move shared ProcessData code to something like `ProcessorBase` and derive both `DB2Processor` and `SqlServerProcessor` from it. You can decide which level implements interface (i.e. you can for whatever reason have only `SqlServerProcessor` to implement `IDatabaseProcessor` interface - it will still pick up ProcessData from base class as implementation of interface).

Comment: Yes, I've done that before, it just seems like an extra step.  Why not just start with an abstract class in the first place?  That just seems to be working around an interface, kind of a hack.

Comment: Interfaces are more flexible if you have multiple *distinct* implementations. I.e. if you ever decide to write tests for classes that use `DatabaseProcessor` (implemented as base class) you'll find that it is hard to implement test version of your base class (unlike interfaces).